# viewForAnnotation problem-Images are not placing properly on google map in iPhone

Tags: iphone

In my Application I have to show the google map along with pin images. I have to place two images according to the condition(branch,atm).In viewForAnnotation method I am doing code for the same,in NSLog I am getting the correct output but annotation images aren't placing properly.
Images are placing inconsistently.Here is my code.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{     
NSString* identifier = @"Pin";  
MKAnnotationView* annView = [searchMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
AddressAnnotation *delegate = annotation;  
Location *newLoc = [searchData objectAtIndex:countATMandBranch];
if (annView == nil) {
annView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"cell"]autorelease];
    annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];         
    if(newLoc.isATM == YES)
    {   
        annView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map_atmicon.png"];
    }

    else if(newLoc.isBranch == YES)
    {   
        annView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map_branchicon.png"];

    }
    //annView.enabled = YES;
    annView.tag = mapView.tag;
    annView.canShowCallout =YES;


}

countATMandBranch++;
return annView;

}
```

If any one aware of this kind of issue please reply to my question.

Answer (score 1):

This might be an offset issue.

When you use a custom image for an `MKAnnotationView` it will by default position it in the center. If you are using a custom 'pin' image this isn't what you want - you want the bottom of the pin to point to the location, rather than the center. If you don't change the offset, when you zoom in/out the position of the annotation will appear to change in comparison to where you think it should be.

You should therefore make sure you've set an appropriate `centerOffset` on your annotation view. I don't see you setting it in the code above, so unless you want your image to be centered exactly on the coordinates required this is probably what's causing it.

Comment: Good answer but you may find more details about centerOffset here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165262/mkannotation-image-offset-with-custom-pin-image