# MKAnnotationView Callout Not Placed Correctly After Rotation

Tags: ios, rotation, mkmapview, mkannotation

If a callout is showing when I rotate the phone from vertical regular to vertical compact, the callout is partially under the navigation bar after rotation.

### How can I get the callout to end up completely enclosed within the map?

[image: Callout Cuff Off]
*This is the phone in vertical compact. I cut off some of the screen for proprietary reasons.*

#### Edit 2

A local community member posted the following code to prevent the zooming in `willTransitionTo` that I complained about below.

```
if let annotation = self.mapView.selectedAnnotations.first {
    var region = self.mapView.region
    region.center = annotation.coordinate
    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```

It works like a champ to prevent the zooming and only results in the centering. Unfortunately, the callout is still partially off screen. If I change the `setCenter` when a pin is selected, it unfortunately results in the callouts being offscreen in a different way. (Something that I already found a hacky workaround regarding deselecting/selecting that is kind of referenced below.)

#### Edit 1

- I have discovered that for some reason calling `setCenter` is also resulting in zooming and I can find no where that I'm causing that. So, that's not good.
- I tried centering on the annotation during `willTransitionTo`. This did not change where the callout is at all and just zooms the map. (See point above.)
- I tried deselecting and then reselecting the annotation in `willTransitionTo`. I get a long pause between the callout disappearing and reappearing. Also, there's zooming (see above). **However,** the callout is within the frame of the map. I am not going with this option because of the "flash" and zooming. (Was making me sea sick.)

#### Old Proposed Answer

*Although I still think this is a valid point on its own*

- An SE in landscape *with more stuff under the map* is just too short to have a functional map.

#### What I Have Tried

- `regionDidChange` is not called then the device is rotated
- I tried to check the frame of the annotation view on rotation (`willTransitionTo`). The frame is already contained in the maps frame
- I confirmed that the top of my map view is pinned to the top layout guide
- I looked at the view hierarchy debugger, and it appears that there are three "private" elements with an origin outside of the map view, but I don't know what to do with this information. (The first `UIView` contained in the `MKPinAnnotationView`, `_UIPopoverView`, and the `UIView` contained in the `UIView` contained in the `_MKCalloutBackgroundMaskView`)
- I am not setting a specific frame in `viewForAnnotation`

#### Other Notes That Might Be Relevant

- I am doing some odd stuff with changing the property on `canShowCallout` because I want to center on the pin after it is selected. But the problem is on rotation, and this code is not getting called again on rotation.
- I do need to account for an SE in "landscape," which might be part of the problem.

All help is appreciated. Especially being shown in a direction to read, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A coworker pointed me to this [answer to MKAnnotation image offset with custom pin image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23138211/4480290).

I am now setting

```
annotationView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
```

in `viewFor annotation` and it is working.

I honestly don't understand why this is fixing the problem, so comments/edits/answers explaining why would be greatly appreciated.